# How does Svelte handle updating an object in an array within an each loop

Tags: svelte

Below is a really simple Svelte component.

When you click the button, it updates pages[2].name. How does Svelte handle this? Does it re-evaluate all 3 DIVs? Or does it know to just modify the 3rd DIV's data because the assignment is to pages[2].name?

```
<script>
    let pages = [{name:'Adam'}, {name:'Barry'}, {name:'Charlie'}];

    function updateName(){
 pages[2].name = 'New Person';
}
</script>

{#each pages as page}
<div>{page.name}</div>
{/each}
<button on:click={updateName}>Update Name</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: After it creates the div's if you change one value it will evaluate all the items in the array.

Example:
If you change 2 names in your array inside the same method the view will only update once.

If you are using a component inside the each loop without ([keying](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks)) and you change a value will behave as only a value changed so the [onMount](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount) method wont be fired.